# How to get the distance between points in my geom and entry point longitude and latitude

Tags: postgis

everyone, I have table name 'geom' and I would like to calculate the distance between points that exist in my table like `0101000020730800001DAB949EE95D4040E124CD1FD3F04340` 
and entry points longitude and latitude and I tried this

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM postgis.cafeecoor
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(geom, ST_MakePoint(32.733792,39.865589)) <= 1 * 1609.34
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `geography` datatype that returns distances in meters.

```sql
SELECT *, st_distance(geom::geography,  ST_MakePoint(32.733792,39.865589)::geography)
FROM postgis.cafeecoor
```

For your example, it returns 1760.32533367 meters.

Depending how your geometry is saved (as a true geometry or as text, with or without a set projection), you might have to add a few extra steps, like creating the geometry and setting its coordinate system

```sql
SELECT *, st_distance(
         st_setsrid(geom::geometry,4326)::geography,
         ST_MakePoint(32.733792,39.865589)::geography)
FROM postgis.cafeecoor;
```

Comment: thank you very much for your helping the second one work for my